# Magento 2 css problem on fronted and backend

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, css, design

**I have the following issue:**

I copied a project from a server to another.

On the original server, everything works fine, but on the new server i don't have any css or js included in my project.

I run all the commands, like:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy(on language) and default,

and reindex I deleted already all the pub folder and regenerated again, i also set the shop on the **production** mode.

I also did this:

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the `virtualType name="developerMaterialization"` section. In that section you'll find an item `name="view_preprocessed"` that needs to be modified or deleted.

You can modify it by changing the contents from

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Delete the files under `pub/static` to get rid of any existing symlinks. You may want to be careful not to delete the .htaccess file.

I am run of ideas, why the css an js not working. 
If i inspect the page, i recive 404 for all the css even the files are there.

For example:

I have 404 for this file

> http://mysite.hypernode.io/pub/static/version1499347283/frontend/Venustheme/namespace/nl_NL/Ves_BaseWidget/css/styles.css

If i acess this in browser i recive 404 but if i remove **version149934728** for link and acessed again like this:

> http://mysite.hypernode.io/pub/static/frontend/Venustheme/namespace/nl_NL/Ves_BaseWidget/css/styles.css
>   the files it's accessed

Does anyone know how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run following query in database

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

or if you have already value for that path, then change it from **1** to **0**.

Then flush cache and deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US nl_NL
```

Comment: When i tried to do this i recive this : Duplicate entry 'default-0-dev/static/sign' for key 'CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH'

Comment: There could be permission issues with new server.

Comment: It seems you have already that path in database. So change its value from 1 to 0.

Comment: This work for me, i was facing same issue and by changing the value in database as shown in above solution solved my problem, or else u must double check the folder access whether its writable or not.